# what does an html form element post as a value if I call $_POST["formname"]?

Tags: php, html, http

`$_POST["formname"]` would post a value and I do not know what it is.

Comment: Hmm. $_POST is a PHP variable. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be the value of the HTML form element who's name is `formname`, provided that the `<form>` with that element has been POSTed to the script.

Comment: +1 good answer (I cannot delete this comment on the mobile site).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a form element whose name is "formname", then nothing will get posted. If you do, then whatever that element's value was would have been posted and retrievable using `$_POST["formname"]`, assuming the request method was "POST" and not "GET".